# Summarize table values in a new dataframe

Tags: r

So I am looking to get some statistics like how many yes and no there are for all columns on the table shown below.

| Question 1 | Question 2 | Question 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| yes | yes | no |
| yes | no | no |
| yes | no | yes |
| no | no | no |
| no | yes | no |

The goal would be to obtain the following dataframe (The columns and rows can be switched, it doesn't have any impact for me) :

| / | Yes | No |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Question 1 | 3 | 2 |
| Question 2 | 2 | 3 |
| Question 3 | 1 | 4 |

The only method I found is pretty long (table(column) --> read.table(text) --> rbind to the previous dataframe created for the previous column) and require a lot of manual manipulation.

Would there be a way to do all of this in one shot ?

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% pivot_longer(everything()) %>% count(name, value) %>% 
    pivot_wider(id_cols = name, names_from = value, values_from = n)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  name          no   yes
  <chr>      <int> <int>
1 Question 1     2     3
2 Question 2     3     2
3 Question 3     4     1
```

Comment: @FrenchStudent, if it does, can you please accept my answer by clicking the 'tick' mark next to the answer.

Comment: Just did, I'm new here sorry I didn't notice it !

Answer (score 0):

In `base R`, we can `unlist` the dataset, and use `table` with the replicated column names

```
table(names(df1)[col(df1)], unlist(df1))
#          no yes
#Question1  2   3
#Question2  3   2
#Question3  4   1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Question1 = c("yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "no"), 
    Question2 = c("yes", "no", "no", "no", "yes"), Question3 = c("no", 
    "no", "yes", "no", "no")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```